# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'isdigit'. Specifying POS of each and every word in sentences list efficiently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nltk, pos-tagger

Suppose I am having lists of list of sentences (in a large corpus) as collections of tokenized words. The sample format is as follows:

The format of tokenized_raw_data is as follows:

```
[['arxiv', ':', 'astro-ph/9505066', '.'], ['seds', 'page', 'on', '``', 
'globular', 'star', 'clusters', "''", 'douglas', 'scott', '``', 'independent', 
'age', 'estimates', "''", 'krysstal', '``', 'the', 'scale', 'of', 'the', 
'universe', "''", 'space', 'and', 'time', 'scaled', 'for', 'the', 'beginner',
 '.'], ['icosmos', ':', 'cosmology', 'calculator', '(', 'with', 'graph', 
'generation', ')', 'the', 'expanding', 'universe', '(', 'american', 
'institute', 'of', 'physics', ')']]
```

I want to apply the `pos_tag`.

What I have tried up to now is as follows.

```
import os, nltk, re
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from unidecode import unidecode
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize
from nltk.tag import pos_tag


def read_data():
    global tokenized_raw_data
    with open("path//merge_text_results_pu.txt", 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors = 'replace') as f:
        raw_data = f.read()
        tokenized_raw_data = '\n'.join(nltk.line_tokenize(raw_data))
read_data()

def function1():
    tokens_sentences = sent_tokenize(tokenized_raw_data.lower())
    unfiltered_tokens = [[word for word in word_tokenize(word)] for word in tokens_sentences]
    tagged_tokens = nltk.pos_tag(unfiltered_tokens)
    nouns = [word.encode('utf-8') for word,pos in tagged_tokens
            if (pos == 'NN' or pos == 'NNP' or pos == 'NNS' or pos ==  'NNPS')]
    joined_nouns_text = (' '.join(map(bytes.decode, nouns))).strip()
    noun_tokens = [t for t in wordpunct_tokenize(joined_nouns_text)]
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))
function1()
```

I am getting the following error.

```
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'isdigit'
```

Please help how to overcome this error in time-efficient manner? Where I am going wrong?

Note: I am using Python 3.7 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this-

```
word_list=[]
for i in range(len(unfiltered_tokens)):
    word_list.append([])
for i in range(len(unfiltered_tokens)): 
    for word in unfiltered_tokens[i]:
        if word[1:].isalpha():
            word_list[i].append(word[1:])
```

then after do

```
tagged_tokens=[]
for token in word_list:
    tagged_tokens.append(nltk.pos_tag(token))
```

You will get your desired results! Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks Somya for the suggestion. But, the sentence in my data is a list which is as follows: ['arxiv', ':', 'astro-ph/9505066', '.']. Similarly, the data is collection of multiple lists of tokenized words. How to obtain pos_tag for each word? Your suggestion clubbed certain words like `thescaleoftheuniversespaceandtimescaledforthebeginner`, whereas I want the pos_tag of the individual strings like: 'the' 'scale' 'of' ...

Comment: Ok i got it! Will look upon it and suggest you.

Comment: Nopes. I have tried. For example: it showing a result as ('americaninstituteofphysics', 'NNS'). I want the pos_tag of individual characters like 'american' 'institute' 'of' 'physics'. Here all four are the individual character

Comment: Suppose if you have a tokenized_raw_data which is lists of lists and not a string, so when you apply: `for token in tokenized_raw_data:
        tagged_tokens = nltk.pos_tag(token)`  you will get `('american', 'JJ'), ('institute', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN'), ('physics', 'NNS')`   in resultset

Comment: See my recent edit @Somya! `f` is a text file containing collection of texts. texts also includes numbers and digits. Example of the text is shown in tokenized_raw_data which is used in `def function1()`

Comment: @M_S take a look at my edited answer and let me know if it worked for you or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185009/discussion-between-m-s-and-somya-avasthi).